# Javascript YUI TreeView: I am unable to change the focus

Tags: javascript, yui

When I click on a node label, it displays the label and currentFocus is correctly set -> it works as expected

When I try to give the focus through my program, I am unable to change the focus:
I have tried this code but it does not work!

```
        // search the node ...
        node.expand();                  // this works fine
        tree.currentFocus = node;       // no focus displayed
```

It seems that since version 2.7.0, a new method focus() should be implemented, but I am unable to find the related documentation (2.8.0r4).